# Exception in C++ with function pointers: Access violation executing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble with function pointers and passing them as inputs to other functions in C++. I've written some simplified code that sums up the trouble that I'm having. I have two .cpp files as below

functions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
typedef double(*real_function)(double);

double one(double x) {
    return double(1);
}

void applyfunction(int length, real_function f, double* result) {
    int j;
    result[0] = 0;
    for (j = 1; j < length; j++) {
        result[j] = f(result[j - 1]);
    }
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

typedef double(*real_function)(double);
real_function one;

void applyfunction(int, real_function, double*);

int main(void) {
    double* result;
    result = (double*)calloc(10, sizeof(double));
    applyfunction(10, one, result);
    return(0);
}
```

When I compile this, I get the following error in Visual Studio 2015

*Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in Project3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.*

What is going wrong? The funny thing is that if we define those functions *one* and *applyfunction* in the source.cpp file (i.e. put all code in a single file), things seem to work. So, I think that it must be something very simple that I am getting wrong. Thank you for any help.

Comment: It crashes during compilation?

Comment: why on earth are you using `calloc` instead of `malloc`?

Comment: Where is 'one' loaded??

Comment: Oh... from the answers, it's not:(

Comment: ..and you would have seen that if you had used the VS debugger.  Why could you net see it in the debugger?   Can the VS debugger not see null pointers?

Comment: @MartinJames I think the OP thought `real_function one;` is equivalent to a function prototype, and didn't realize it's actually creating a variable that he should look for in the debugger.

Comment: Orite.. OP - you cannot call through a function pointer until you first load it with a valid address of a function that matches the prototype.

Answer (score 3):

```
real_function one;
```

This creates a global variable `one` which is initialized to a null pointer.

```
applyfunction(10, one, result);
```

You then pass that null pointer to `applyfunction`...

```
result[j] = f(result[j - 1]);
```

...wherein you try to call it, generating the null pointer exception.

To fix this, don't create a variable `one` in `Source.cpp`. Instead, add a prototype that matches the definition in `functions.cpp`. In other words, replace `real_function one;` with

```
double one(double x);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's completely obvious when you explain it like that. I was naming a new function pointer 'one' rather than using the earlier defined 'one'. I thought that I was just giving a function prototype. Is there a way to use the typedef to make a more brief function prototype at the top of the Sources file? Or, is this not recommended anyway?

Comment: My preferred approach would be to put the prototype in a header file that both cpp files `#include`.

Answer (score 1):

```
real_function one;
```

doesn't declare the function `one` in the other file; it defines a function pointer called `one`. Because it's global (and thus has static storage), it's initialized to null. Your program crashes because it's trying to call a null pointer.

One way to fix this is to change

```
typedef double(*real_function)(double);
```

to

```
typedef double real_function(double);
```

This way `real_function` actually names a function type (not a pointer).